# sorting column data into a raw by unique data

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I sort in a row by the unique value of such data? For instance, I would like to compare the data on the value column, such as 2,3 4, or more values depending on the unique ID? This is 14 unique ID data for compare their values.

```
Unique ID               Value
1,707,925,242.000000    12
1,707,925,242.000000    8
1,858,484,130.000000    25
1,968,378,743.000000    12
2,612,459,772.000000    15
2,718,123,256.000000    20
2,718,123,256.000000    0
2,781,397,191.000000    0
6,041,837,851.000000    5
6,041,837,851.000000    0
6,238,277,971.000000    4
6,238,277,971.000000    10
6,238,277,971.000000    7
6,238,277,971.000000    10
6,317,261,953.000000    12
7,832,343,219.000000    7
8,885,412,430.000000    12
9,065,557,515.000000    10
9,715,283,795.000000    15
9,715,283,795.000000    10
9,753,550,632.000000    25
9,753,550,632.000000    15
```

I meant, like this:

```
                    Value 1    Value 2    Value 3    Value 4    Value 5
1,707,925,242.00    12         8
1,858,484,130.00
1,968,378,743.00    25
2,612,459,772.00    12
2,718,123,256.00    15         20
2,781,397,191.00    0
6,041,837,851.00    0          5
6,238,277,971.00    0          4          10         7
```

Comment: This data already appears to be sorted by the unique id column.  What do you mean by "compare"?  Please can you [edit] and try to explain further?

Comment: Thanks Paul. I edited my question and the format I like to use. I would like to sort by the values agains the the unique ID.

Comment: I edited your question to try to improve the appearance, but it still doesn't make sense. Why isn't `1,858,484,130.00` matched with `25`? Why isn't `1,968,378,743.00` matched with `12`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your example contains some errors (as @g-man already noticed). If these are indeed error's, you can create a very similar overview using pivot tables. Check [this introduction](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/PivotTable-I-Get-started-with-PivotTable-reports-in-Excel-2007-bfe774d3-3e20-46f7-b6a3-f7984855d665) to pivot tables from Microsoft. I'll give you two layout options that come close to what you are looking for (although not exactly the same).

- Select your data
- Inset a Pivot table, based on your data
- Put the fields "Unique ID" and "Value" in the Row Labels window.
- Select "Pivot table options" (right-click on the pivot table) and under the tab "Display", check "Classic PivotTable layout". Under the tab "Totals & Filters", uncheck both "Show grand totals..." options.

Your pivot table should look like this. It's almost your table, except that Value1, Value2, etc. are located in the rows below the Unique ID's instead of left to them.

[image: Pivot table solution 1]

As an alternative, you can make a matrix. **After** you setup the pivot table like above, make the following adjustments:

- Drag the "Values" from the "Row labels" to the "Column labels" section.
- Also, drag the "Values" field from the Field list to the "Values" field.
- Change the field settings of the last field from "Sum of Value" of "Min of Value".

Now your pivot table looks like this:

[image: Pivot table solution 2]

Almost the same as you wanted, but (added feature!) the same values are vertically aligned.

I suggest you play around with the pivot table options. It's a very powerful tool.